# Roman culture for converted CK2 game

Tags: crusader-kings-2, europa-universalis-iv

I finished Crusader Kings 2 (CK2) where I own the Roman Empire. I converted the save game and bring it to Europa Universalis 4 (EU4). If I were to create Roman Empire in EU4, regions with my primary culture would change its culture into Roman culture. However with converted save, those region would still have Greek as its culture. My primary culture is also Greek, which is what it was in CK2.

**How can I have Roman culture in CK2 converted EU4 game?**

In addition, in my converted game, England have Anglo-Saxon culture which is what it was in CK2. Normally Anglo-Saxon would belong to Lost Culture together with Roman  culture, however right now, if I hover over it, it says that Anglo-Saxon belongs to British culture group. Is there a way to turn it into Lost Culture group so that it would belong to the same group as Roman culture?

Answer (score 1):

So, what is your situation? You played CK2 as Byzantium and conquered most of the Roman Empire, but did not reform it?

There are two ways to reform the Roman Empire in EU4.

1) Reform it in CK2 and transfer the save, you should then immediately start as the Roman Empire in EU4.

2) Fulfill all the objectives described [here](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Roman_Empire). Then you can reform the Roman Empire by decision, which also changes your primary culture to Roman as well as all provinces of your primary culture to roman.

Regarding the Anglo-Saxon. I believe, Anglo-Saxon only belongs to the lost culture group, if it was part of the roman empire. As the anglo-saxon provinces belonged to England, they were converted to the British culture group. Or a patch changed it, as it makes sense that anglo-saxon is a british culture.